# Invoking Parent Window after Report Generation

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, windows-forms-designer

I m developing WindowsFormApplication , in which One main form exists with several child forms.
One of my forms generates report, after which I want to invoke my parent form by closing all other intermediate form which are invoked as a part of report generation. I want to invoke parent window when the user tries to close report by using common close button 'X' (button used to close a common window in Windows Operating System).

How can I access my parentform/startupform from any of my child forms anytime?
and How can I close all other child forms excluding the main form when Last form terminated?

Somebody please help me..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: How you showed your `final report` form? I would like to know how you organize your forms. For example, I usually have my child/sub form members defined in the class of my main form. So I can show any sub/child form in my main form easily.

Comment: I created every form individually and Calling them whenever needed by creating an object on particular form like: In first form.. secondform fr = new secondform(); fr.show();

Answer (score 1):

To show your startup form when closing your final form, you can add event handler for the event `FormClosed` of your final form like this:

```
FinalForm f = new FinalForm();
f.FormClosed += (s,e) => {
   StartupForm sf = new StartupForm();
   sf.Show;
   //if your StartupForm is defined somewhere
   //just call sf.Show();
};
//If you are using VS 2005 or below, you have to define a method for FormClosed event handler (unable to use the lambda expression above
private void FormClosedHandler(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e){
  StartupForm sf = new StartupForm();
   sf.Show;
   //if your StartupForm is defined somewhere
   //just call sf.Show();
}
//Register the FormClosed event with the event handler above
f.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(FormClosedHandler);

//show your final form
f.Show();
//if this form is closed, the event FormClosed will be raised and the corresponding event handler (we added above) will be called.
```

Comment: what is s and e in this code.. I got the error 'e' undeclared

Comment: @RavitejA I guess you are using VS 2005 or below which doesn't support `Lambda expression`. What I wrote is `lambda expression`.

Comment: I m using vs2008... can u plz elaborate the event handler when closing of final form happens?

Answer (score 0):

The Application object in a Winforms app has an OpenForms collection that contains a reference to all the opened forms. You can get a reference to a form from that collection and call Close() on it to close it.

Further to your comment, in the OnClosing event of finalreport you can run this code

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (f.GetType().ToString().Contains("start"))
                    f.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: please suggest me some code.. my start up form name is "start" and final form name is "finalreport".. I want to invoke my startup form when i close the form "finalreport"

Comment: I tried it.. but startup form is not getting invoked when i close final form :(